# All possible combinations of a 2D array

Tags: c#, java, vba, combinations, multidimensional-array

I want to generate all possible combinations from a 2D [m x n] array except for the first element of each array. That element will stand for the 'type' signifying the rest elements. For example, if I've an array

```
shirts[][] = 
{
  {"colour", "red", "blue", "green", "yellow"},
  {"cloth", "cotton", "poly", "silk"},
  {"type", "full", "half"}
};
```

The desired output should be combination of all the possibilities of shirt. For the above example,

```
colour red
colour blue
...
cloth silk
type full
type half
colour red cloth cotton
colour red cloth poly
...
colour yellow type half
cloth cotton type full
...
cloth silk type half
colour red cloth cotton type full
...
colour yellow cloth silk type half
```

I tried something like this (also took help from other Stack Overflow [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n) )

```
String shirts[][] = 
{
  {"colour", "red", "blue", "green", "yellow"},
  {"cloth", "cotton", "poly", "silk"},
  {"type", "full", "half"}
};

majorCombinations = new int[possibilities][shirts.length];

int currentCombination;
int offset = 1;

for (int i=0; i < shirts.length; i++)
{
    currentCombination = 0;
    while (currentCombination < possibilities)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < shirts[i].length; j++)
        {
            for (int k=0; k < offset; k++)
            {
                if (currentCombination < possibilities)
                {
                    majorCombinations[currentCombination][i] = shirts[i][j];
                    currentCombination++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    offset *= shirts[i].length;
}
```

but it gives values of ALL n combinations only i.e.

```
colour cloth type
colour cloth full
...
yellow silk half
```

It doesn't take into account smaller combinations and it ain't even generic i.e. for an [m x n] array (n need not be fixed). A help in VBA would be highly appreciated. I'm comfortable with C, Java and C#.
Thanks in advance :)

**Edit:**

This is different than the [question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093622/generating-all-possible-combinations). This one is not a Cartesian Product wherein *one* element be taken from each array in question. The output I require doesn't put this restriction; hence the number of combinations in this scenario > number of combinations in the linked question.
Also, the first column is a descriptor of the contents and must accompany the content.

Comment: A link to a similar answered question would also be welcome.

Comment: Wouldn't it help to simply let `j` start from `1` instead of `0`?

Comment: @Liam made the edit as to why this isn't the duplicate

Answer (score 3):

[Link to Original Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9521790/1004522)

For two arrays two nested loops should do:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != c[0].length ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j != c[1].length ; j++) {
        System.out.writeln(""+c[0][i]+c[1][j]);
    }
}
```

For more nesting you would need a recursive or an equivalent stack-based solution.

```
void combos(int pos, char[][] c, String soFar) {
    if (pos == c.length) {
         System.out.writeln(soFar);
         return;
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i != c[pos].length ; i++) {
        combos(pos+1, c, soFar + c[pos][i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine upto a limit i.e. if I've got a 2D array of length m, it produces combinations of size m. What I need are combinations of size 1 to m. Thanks for taking the time to answer; it shall provide some insight.

Answer (score 0):

Is what you want, a Cartesian product?

```
var colours = new[]{"colour - red", "colour - blue", "colour - green", "colour - yellow"};
var cloth = new[] {"cloth - cotton", "cloth - poly", "cloth - silk"};
var type = new[]{"type - full", "type - half"};

var combinations = from c in colours
                   from cl in cloth
                   from t in type
                   select new[]{c, cl, t};
```

Comment: Thanks Dave; the approach was quite good. It worked in SQL, but I am in need of more Java like approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < shirts[0].length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < shirts[1].length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < shirts[2].length; k++) {
if (i != 0)
                    System.out.print(shirts[0][0] + " " + shirts[0][i]
                            + " ");
                if (j != 0)
                    System.out.print(shirts[1][0] + " " + shirts[1][j]
                            + " ");
                if (k != 0)
                    System.out.print(shirts[2][0] + " " + shirts[2][k]
                            + " ");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That's simple and great! It works fair enough for 3 arrays.