# How to initialize a 2D String ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

How to create a 2D `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` like

```
competition = [["A", "B"], 
["B", "C"],
["C", "A"]]
```

how can I declare it initialized during declaration? or the only way to do it as following

```
 ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> competitions = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<>();
        x.add("A");
        x.add("B");

        ArrayList<String> y = new ArrayList<>();
        y.add("B");
        y.add("C");

        ArrayList<String> z = new ArrayList<>();
        z.add("C");
        z.add("A");

competitions.add(x);
competitions.add(y);
competitions.add(z);
```

Comment: `ArrayList` is a class like any other. Unlike arrays, it doesn't have a short-hand literal representation. But you could make a 2d-array and then [convert it to an `ArrayList`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447780/convert-two-dimensional-array-to-list-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like that if I understand your need:

```java
List<List<String>> list = Arrays.asList(
           Arrays.asList("A", "B"),
           Arrays.asList("B", "C"),
           Arrays.asList("C", "A")
);
```

EDIT:

```java
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B")),
            new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("B", "C")),
            new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("C", "A"))
));
```

Comment: its possible in List and not in ArrayList? how to convert List to ArrayList

Comment: When you see `ArrayList<E>` declaration, class implements `List<E>`, so probably you have all what you want directly. But if you want `ArrayList`, use @h4kcr0o response.

Comment: Need it as ArrayList, added comment above

Comment: I modified answer, you have to create all arrays with `new ArrayList<>()`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you are trying to create an arrayList from an Array ou can do it with

```
new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Comment: No, below doesn't work 
**ArrayList<> c2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B"), Arrays.asList("B", "C"));**

Comment: Because this is not an array you should type something like : ArrayList<> c2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(["A", "B"]) you missed '['

Comment: Didn't work
**ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> c2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(["A", "B"]);**