# Get all possible combinations from a 2D int array

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get all possible combinations from a 2D array, let's say that I have an array full of numbers;

```
int[][] Values = new int[][] {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
```

What I want is combinations like this:

```
[1-2], [2-1], [3-2], [2-3], [3-3], [2-2], [1-3], [1-1]
```

Basically the same number can get used over and over again, but I don't want to get the same combination in them. I hope I could explain what I'm trying to do. I couldn't find other answers that did what I wanted.

Edit:

I tried the answers from [All possible combinations of a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326038/all-possible-combinations-of-a-2d-array) too but it didn't work, this question doesn't have anything to do with that question. I want arrays with numbers that can be used again, I don't want numbers to be unique.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: I tried a few things but I can't find their links now, and I'm not on the device I made the project on so I can't give any examples of what I tried to do.

Comment: Please check this and let me know if this helps 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326038/all-possible-combinations-of-a-2d-array

Comment: No it didn't do what I want, why is my question even closed and put as a duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for *Cartesian Join*. Given *jagged array* (`int[][]` is *jagged* array, not *2D* one)

```
  int[][] Values = new int[][] { 
    new int[] { 1, 2 }, 
    new int[] { 3, 4 }, 
  };
```

You can `Join` it with itself as

```
  var result = Values
    .SelectMany(line => line)              // flatten
    .Join(Values.SelectMany(line => line), // flatten
          x => true,                       
          y => true,                        
         (x, y) => new int[] { x, y });
```

In case of *2D array* `int [,]`

```
  int[,] Values = new int[,] { 
    { 1, 2 }, 
    { 3, 4 }, 
  };
```

you can use the same idea, but with `OfType` instead of `SelectMany`:

```
  var result = Values
    .OfType<int>()              // flatten
    .Join(Values.OfType<int>(), // flatten
          x => true,                       
          y => true,                        
         (x, y) => new int[] { x, y });
```

Let's have a look:

```
  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
    .Select(line => $"[{string.Join(", ", line)}]")));
```

**Outcome:**

```
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[2, 1]
[2, 2]
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
[3, 1]
[3, 2]
[3, 3]
[3, 4]
[4, 1]
[4, 2]
[4, 3]
[4, 4]
```

**Edit:** To get all combinations of `3` items (i.e. `{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2} .. {4, 4, 4}`) you can add one more `Join`. For jagged array `[,]` it can be

```
  var result = Values
    .SelectMany(line => line)              // flatten
    .Join(Values.SelectMany(line => line), // flatten
       x => true,
       y => true,
       (x, y) => (a: x, b: y))
    .Join(Values.SelectMany(line => line), // flatten
       x => true,
       y => true,
       (x, y) => new int[] {x.a, x.b, y});
```

To get all 4 items combinations you can add yet another `Join`, etc.:

```
  var result = Values
    .SelectMany(line => line)              // flatten
    .Join(Values.SelectMany(line => line), // flatten
       x => true,
       y => true,
       (x, y) => (a: x, b: y))
    .Join(Values.SelectMany(line => line), // flatten
       x => true,
       y => true,
       (x, y) => (a: x.a, b: x.b, c: y))
    .Join(Values.SelectMany(line => line), // flatten
       x => true,
       y => true,
       (x, y) => new int[] {x.a, x.b, x.c, y});
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it change how many numbers are in one combination depending on the count of how many arrays are in the 2D array?

Comment: @MrEAZL: if you want to find out combinations of `3` items i.e. `{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3} .. {4, 4, 4}` you should use nested `Join`s: find combinations of `2` items add one more `Join` to get all combiations of `3` items

Comment: I'm pretty new to those stuff in C# and I don't know how to do it, I would be really happy if you can edit your post and put an example or something.

Comment: @MrEAZL: I've edited the answer, I add a code to get all 3 item cmbinations