# How to force jumps with std::next_permutation

Tags: c++, c++11, permutation

Is it possible to manipulate the current permutation sequence in order to skip (in my case) "useless" sequences?

If that isn't possible, would a custom implementation of a permutation iteration be as fast as std::next_permutation?

An example:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ...

1 3 2 4 5 6 7 ...

Detecting that "2" at the 2nd position isn't valid, leads to skipping every permutation which begins with "1, 2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to write some custom rules for that. A smart way to do this would be to write a code, in which whenever you have a set of permutations which are not valid, you jump to the next permutation you can get which will be valid.

For eg, in the above case, knowing that 2 at 2nd position is invalid, you could write the code to swap 2 and 3, and ensure that the permutation then achieved is the smallest one possible with 3 in that location, and so on.

Also, if you were writing your own implementation of next_permuation, ensure that the internal functioning is as close to that of next_permutation. You can read about it here: [std::next_permutation Implementation Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483060/stdnext-permutation-implementation-explanation)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, and it's not hard once you understand how `next_permutation` works.

In short, there are N! permutations of N items. However, only one of them is sorted. `1 2 3 4 5 6 7` for instance is the first of 5040 permutations. Viewed as a string (lexicographically) the next permutation is the one that sorts directly after that: `1 2 3 4 5 7 6`. It particular, the first 5 elements are unaltered. The *next* permutation alters the 5th element because the last 2 elements are in reverse order.

So, in your case, once you've found an illegal permutation, you'd have to explicitly calculate the next legal permutation by sort order. If `1 2` is the only illegal prefix then `1 3 2 4 5 6 7` is obviously the next valid permutation.

In general, look at your illegal pattern, determine which positions you have to *increase* because they violate constraints, and come up with the next valid values for those positions (if your pattern is small enough, you can brute-force this). Then fill in the remaining numbers in sorted order.