# Function that returns all possibilities of rearranging of an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, recursion, language-agnostic

I'm a newbee programmer, and i'm actually doing some programming challenges. And here's my question:

How can I create a function that returns all rearranging possibilities of an array?

Exemple (in pseudo-code):

```
Array = ["aba", "bbb", "bab"] //this array have 6 possible arrangements

function arrayRearangement(Array) {
   //receive the array and return all array arrangement possibilities (6)
}
arrayRearrangement(Array) = [["aba", "bbb", "bab"], 
                             ["aba", "bab", "bbb"],
                             ["bbb", "aba", "bab"], 
                             ["bbb", "bab", "aba"],
                             ["bab", "bbb", "aba"],
                             ["bab", "aba", "bbb"]]
```

If possible, please, give-me the solution in pseudo-code (I prefer to implement by myself).

But It can be written in your favorite programming language.

Obs.: Sorry about any possible english mistake, or if the topic is repeated, i have been searched a lot and don't found anything

Comment: Nearly a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11483060/179910

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably want to learn more about [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) in order to achieve it.

In backtracking, you use recursion to go over all possible solutions of the problem.

In your case (pseudo code):

```
GetAllPermutations(elements):
  result = []
  GetAllPermutations(set(elements), [], result)
  return result

GetAllPermutations(elements, so_far, result):
  if elements.empty():
    result.add(so_far)
    return
  for x in elements:
    elements.remove(x)  // Note while implementing: this is problematic since modifying while iterating, there are ways to overcome it
    so_far.append(x)
    // This is the recursive call, which "assumes" x is set and checks all possible other solutions
    GetAllPermutations(elements, so_far, result)
    // set back the state for next iterations where x is viable selection
    so_far.remove_last()
    elements.add(x)
```