# Combining 6 sets of 2 elements in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, combinations

1I'm making a "Virtual Keyboard" for typing passwords in Java.

The password must have 6 numeric chars and each button has 2 possible values.
So, there are 2 values possible for each pressed key.

For example: after pressing 6 buttons, I have an array of 6 objects, each one representing the possible values for each character of the password, respectively:

(1 , 5) for char1
(3 , 2) for char2
(7 , 4) for char3
(1 , 5) for char4
(9 , 0) for char5
(8 , 6) for char6

How can I make all combination of 6-digit-strings with these entries? (I guess that would be 64 combinations: 2ˆ6)

Example of valid combinations:

137198
537198
127198
537196

and so on...

Comment: You can use this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920315/permutation-of-array)

Comment: Don't think so. I'm not permuting all elements. I'm combining two elements for each char. Witch will give me 2ˆ6 combinations...

Comment: Can the same button be pressed more than once?

Comment: This seems rather easy to solve with recursion, have you tried?

Comment: Actually, each time the user presses the button, I'm re-shuffling all the numbers. But I save a record of the two possible values.

Comment: I've tried, but couldn't find a way

Comment: arr[pos] = val[pos][1];
rec(pos+1);
arr[pos] = val[pos][2]; rec(pos+1);

Comment: and just output your arr[] when pos is 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a sequence of n buttons, where each can assume 2 values, this problem reduces to counting from 0 to 2^n-1 since you can interpret each bit at position i as one of the two values that each button can assume. For n=3:

```
000 -> 137
001 -> 134
010 -> 127
011 -> 124
100 -> 537
...
```

So just count from 0 to 2^6 and you automatically get your solution.

This is the same way you would go about generating the 2^n subsets of a set of n elements.

Comment: So after having all 2ˆ6 numbers I'll have to loop over every bit of every number, generating a string?

Comment: Well I would increment the counter and generate the string. No need to keep 2^6 numbers in memory!

Answer (score 1):

Just create every combination possible and check if each of them is the correct one