# find the shortest path on map with multiple locations and show on android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, shortest-path

I have multiple locations and want to cover all locations with shortest path.I have used google shortest path api but it can works only between two locations.Is there any library or algorithm available for shortest path between multiple locations ?

Comment: So this means what?  You want to visit multiple locations?  And find the shortest distance between them?  (Based on your edit: try [Traveling Salesman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) problem.)

Comment: HI, I want to visit multiple locations and want to see on map.

Comment: hi - is this statement correct: you want to visit all locations and you want to know which route would be the shortest? then maybe you might be interested in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: Yes Martin,we need exactly same that you are saying.

Comment: referring to that wiki-pedia articel, the brute force approach is very easy but has a practical limit of 20 locations (if you're using it on a mobil device you should limit the locations to n<=9 because brute force needs n! (n-faculity) routes to calculate...) 9! = 362880 possible routes

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920315/permutation-of-array to find permutation to find all possible routes...

Comment: why don't you use waypoints with optimize flag? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Waypoints

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I'd implement Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm is only really applicable to mathematical graphs. It isn't appropriate for physical pathing.

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm is fine. There is nothing wrong with it for physical routes, which are calculated on exactly the same sort of graph as any other routes. However, A*, which is a modification of Dijkstra, is faster.