# How to find the maximum possible sum of numbers in arrays drawn from a unique array index

Tags: java, arrays

I need to find maximum possible sum of numbers in arrays but number must be drawn from a unique array index...just like that:

```
double maxSum = 0;

double a = {1.0 , 2.0, 3.0};
double b = {4.0 , 5.0, 6.0};
double c = {7.0 , 8.0, 9.0};

sum = a[0] + b[1] + c[2];

// or sum = a[0] + b[2] + c[1]
// or sum = a[1] + b[0] + c[2]
// etc. - how to do that for i arrays and for j numbers in array?

if(sum >=maxSum){
maxSum = sum;
}
```

this is what I did - but don't have any clue what to do next...

```
    public ArrayList<Double[]> tempArrayCreator() {
    ArrayList<Double[]> lists = new ArrayList<Double[]>();

    Double[] list1 = { 6.0, 7.0, 6.0 };
    Double[] list2 = { 4.5, 6.0, 6.75 };
    Double[] list3 = { 6.0, 5.0, 9.0 };

    lists.add(list1);
    lists.add(list2);
    lists.add(list3);

    return lists;
}

public double maxPossibleSum(ArrayList<Double[]> lists) {

    double result = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < lists.get(i).length; j++) {

        // ???

        }
    }

    return result;

}
```

edit. example:

```
list1 = { 1, 5, 2};
list2 = { 9, 3, 7};
list3 = { 8, 4, 9};

possible solutions:
list1[0] + list2[1] + list3[2] = 13
list1[0] + list2[2] + list3[1] = 12
list1[1] + list2[0] + list3[2] = 23 <-- here it is!
list1[1] + list2[2] + list3[0] = 20
list1[2] + list2[0] + list3[1] = 15
list1[2] + list2[1] + list3[0] = 13
```

Comment: Why not add the value from the array into your result variable?

Comment: Am I right in thinking that: a) All of the source arrays will have the same number of elements and b) Each unique index where 0 <= index < arrayLength must be used once and only once?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you're trying to do. It sounds like you want to sum the largest number from each list? Can you clarify your expected result.

Comment: I think it is specified in comments in code "how to do that for i arrays and for j numbers in array?"

Comment: @Moob I want to get maximum sum from numbers drawn from unique array index - in my example I should get 21.0 - list1[0]+list2[1]+list3[2]

Comment: i think i can explain, you need to find the numbers (a number from each array) that if you sum together will result the maximum possible sum, the result could be array1[4] + array2[11] + arrayN[X] based on where N is the count of arrays

Comment: @GHC yes - every array will have the same number of elements and each index I can use only once

Comment: @Moob in fact, the correct result is 22.75, check my answer below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you want to get the list of all the Permutations of your indexes.

```
{[0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 2, 0], [2, 1, 0], [2, 0, 1]}
```

For example, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14444037/1107536) gives a way to do it:

```
public static List<List<Integer>> getAllPermutations(int arraySize) {
    List<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        elements.add(i);
    }
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    getAllPermutations(result, elements, 0);
    return result;
}

private static void getAllPermutations(List<List<Integer>> result, List<Integer> elements, int k) {
    for (int i = k; i < elements.size(); i++) {
        java.util.Collections.swap(elements, i, k);
        getAllPermutations(result, elements, k + 1);
        java.util.Collections.swap(elements, k, i);
    }
    if (k == elements.size() - 1) {
        result.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(elements));
    }
}
```

Then you iterate through all your permutations:

```
public double maxPossibleSum(ArrayList<Double[]> lists) {
    List<List<Integer>> allPermutations = getAllPermutations(3);
    double maxSum = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    for (List<Integer> permutation : allPermutations) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < permutation.size(); i++) {
            Integer index = permutation.get(i);
            sum += lists.get(i)[index];
        }
        if (sum > maxSum) {
            maxSum = sum;
        }
    }
    return maxSum;
}
```

Comment: Please explicit your sources. Otherwise proposed code is fine

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
        Double[] tmp = list.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < tmp.length; j++) {
            result += tmp[j];     
        }           

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

inside your for loop just add

```
result+=lists.get(i)[j];
```

Comment: thank you for this - but in that way I get sum of all numbers in all arrays - and what I want is to get maximum possible sum of only one number from each array (and in unique array index as well)

Comment: can you put an example in your question? its pretty confusing to understand what you are really asking for