# All possible combination of dynamic String of various length?

Tags: java, string

I need to print all possible combination of any String without any repetition of character,
for Example suppose input is-`ABC`
desired combinations are-`ABC` `ACB` `BCA` `BAC` `CAB` `CBA`

Below is my code which is running fine-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String name="abcd";
    char[] nameArray=name.toCharArray();
    String result = null;
    int flag=0;
    for(int i=0;i<nameArray.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<nameArray.length;j++){
            for(int k=0;k<nameArray.length;k++){
                for(int l=0;l<nameArray.length;l++){
                     result=""+nameArray[i]+nameArray[j]+nameArray[k]+nameArray[l];
                     flag=0;
                        for(Character c:nameArray){
                            if(!result.contains(c.toString())){
                                flag=1;
                            }
                        }
                        if( flag==0){
                            System.out.println(result);
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

problem with this is this is a static,like- we are using 4 for loop since length of String is 4.How to write same code for dynamic String of various length?
also its time complexity is very high(n^n),but this is not such major issue.

Comment: create a recursive function.

Comment: I also tried with `recursion`,but unable to write for dynamic length.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permutation of array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920315/permutation-of-array)

Comment: Also related: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/36300/31562

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this blog for you"

> http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2013/06/find-all-possible-permutations-of-given.html

Uses `recursion` and explains exactly what he's doing. You can remove your duplicates afterwards or at the point in the code where he prints the permutation.