# Java putting all permutations of an Int array into another array without repeats

Tags: java, permutation

There are many other questions on Stack Overflow like this, but this one asks for something different than the others. I want to know how to take all permutations of an int array, without repeats, and put them in another 2D array. For example, the input:
    `{1,2,3}`
the output:

```
{1,2,3}
{1,3,2}
{2,1,3}
{2,3,1}
{3,1,2}
{3,2,1}
```

How can I accomplish this? I'd like just a verbal walk through on how to do this, or even better some code. My question differs from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920315/permutation-of-array)
because the linked one uses C++ functions to accomplish this. I use Java.

Thanks

Comment: are there any duplicates in the input?

Comment: @karthik No, there are no

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permutation of array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920315/permutation-of-array)

Comment: @Anteaters, the question linked provides a java answer aswell

Comment: @WorldSEnder That is true, but it prints it, and doesn't put it in an array

Comment: @Anteaters, that is an easy change, you shouldn't expect to get all the code chewed for you. I am sure you can adapt the change so that it stores them in a list.

Comment: Code written in another language can for the most part be easily read through and implemented in another language.

Answer (score 2):

Java is an object-oriented language and so I believe it is useful to consider what objects your problem might contain.

One thing that immediately jumps out of your problem domain is the triple-set of integers, so why not define this as an object:

```
public class Triad {

    private final int[] components;

    public Triad(int... numbers) {
        this.components = numbers;
        if (components.length != 3) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    @Override public boolean equals(Object ob) {
        if (ob == this) return true;            
        if (!(ob instanceof Triad)) return false;
        Triad test = (Triad) ob;
        return Arrays.equals(this.components, test.components);
    }

    @Override public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(this.components);
    }
}
```

Note that `Triad` defines an `equals()` method and a `hashCode()` method.  This is important for a couple of reasons.  `Triad` is a *value class*, i.e. instances of `Triad` represent values rather than something active.  Value classes typically:

- should be immutable (as we have defined Triad so far, it is immutable)
- have well-formed equals() and hashCode() methods

the last property above allows instances to be used without fear with the Java Collections Framework.  Now let's put the Collections Framework to use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Set<Triad> triads = new HashSet<Triad>();

    Triad inputTriad;

    while (true) {
        int[] numbers = ... // read in data from some source
        if (numbers == null) break;
        inputTriad = new Triad(numbers);
        triads.add(inputTriad);
    }

    // after the loop has completed, the HashSet instance triad will contain
    // all your input triads.  The contract of HashSet guarantees that there
    // will be no duplicates.
    :
    :
}
```

If you must have your result in int arrays, it is now a simple matter to iterate through the HashSet instance and assign the component values of each element to your result arrays.

Comment: Great answer. Up-voted, but my guess is the OP is looking for a way to do this using arrays. The question sounds like a Java homework exercise. Your answer is for next semester's Advanced Java course! ;)