# Efficient algorithm to print sum of elements at all possible subsequences of length 2 to n+1

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, discrete-mathematics, subsequence

I will start with an example. Suppose we have an array of size **3** with elements `a`, `b` and `c` like: (*where `a`, `b` and `c` are some numerical values*)

> |1 | 2| 3|
>  |a | b| c|

(*Assume index starts from 1 as shown in the example above*)

Now all possible increasing sub-sequence of length **2** are:

> 12 23 13

so the sum of product of elements at those indexes is required, that is, `ab+bc+ac`

For length **3** we have only one increasing sub-sequence, that is, 123 so `abc` should be printed.
For length **4** we have no sequence so `0` is printed and the program terminates.

So output for the given array will be:

```
ab+bc+ac,abc,0
```

So for example if the elements `a`, `b` and `c` are 1, 2 and 3 respectively then the output should be `11,6,0`

Similarly, for an array of size **4** with elements a,b,c,d the output will be:

```
ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd,abc+abd+acd+bcd,abcd,0
```

and so on...

Now obviously brute force will be too inefficient for large value of array size. I was wondering if there is an efficient algorithm to compute the output for an array of given size?

**Edit 1:** I tried finding a pattern. For example for an array  of size **4**:

`The first value we need is     :(ab+ac+bc)+d(a+b+c)= ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd  (Take A=ab+ac+bd)
then the second value we need is:(abc)     +d(A)    = abc+abd+acd+bcd(B=abc)
then the third value we need is : (0)      +d(B)    = abcd(Let's take 0 as C)
then the fourth value we need is:          +d(C)    = 0`

But it still requires a lot of computation and I can't figure out an efficient way to implement this.

**Edit 2**: My question is different then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920315/permutation-of-array) since:

1. I don't need all possible permutations. I need all possible increasing sub-sequences from length 2 to n+1.
2. I also don't need to print all possible such sequences, I just need the value thus obtained (*as explained above*) and hence I am looking for some maths concept or/and some dynamic programming approach to solve this problem efficiently.
3. Note I am finding the set of all possible such increasing sub-sequences based on the index value and then computing based on the values at those index position as explained above.

Comment: Can we assume that the input array will always be sorted ascending order?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Please check the edit.

Comment: A sub sequence _is_ a permutation.  You are basically doing `r` choose `N`, where `N` is the length of the array.

Comment: where `N` varies from 2 to N. So it is `r` choose `2` first, then `r` choose `3` ....till `r` choose `N` and for all of these we need to print the value thus obtained as explain in the question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Also whether the array is sorted or not doesn't matter since the index will always be sorted.

Comment: I don't know the solution well, but if I recall the problem correctly, it can be solved using some special matrices and their multiplication. I've googled a little: sorry, can't find neither the problem, nor the solution.

Comment: @SergeRogatch googling "special matrices and their multiplication" didn't lead me anywhere :) It would be really helpful if you could recall a bit more.

Comment: @fjardon But here author mentions `abc+abd+acd+bcd` and `all possible increasing sub-sequences from length 2 to n+1.`

Comment: @MBo you're perfectly right

Comment: @MBo that's what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a post that seems to have disappeared pointed out one way is to get a  recurrence relation. Let S(n,k) be the sum over increasing subsequences (of 1..n) of length k of the product of the array elements indexed by the sequence. Such a subsequence either ends in n or not; in the first case it's the concatenation of a subsequence of length k-1 of 1..n-1 and {n}; in the second case it's a subsequence of 1..n-1 of length k. Thus:

```
S(n,k) = S(n-1,k) + A[n] * S(n-1,k-1)
```

For this always to make sense we need to add:

```
S(n,0) = 1
S(n,m) = 0 for m>n
```