# Issue in swapping specific array elements

Tags: java, arrays, swap

The following is no homework. I'm just trying to write my own permutation code. I have an idea but I have problems in writing this idea as code.

As example the input is `myArray={1,2,3};`

Then the output is supposed to be:

```
1 2 3
2 1 3
2 3 1
3 2 1
3 1 2
1 3 2
```

I figured out it's possible by switching the first element with second, then switch second with third (however not entirely possible, but I know I need this).

That's why my question is how can I do this in Java?

I have `1 2 3` and I want switch first element with second, so I get `2 1 3`. Print this. Now I want switch second element with third, I get `2 3 1`, print it. Repeat `n!` times where n is `myArray` length.

I tried to do this with the following code but it seems like I'm far away from it :(

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] myArray = {1,2,3};

        for(int x=0; x<6; x++){
            for(int i=0; i<myArray.length-1; i++){
                int temp=myArray[i];
                myArray[i]=myArray[i+1];
                myArray[i+1]=temp;
            }
            for(int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
                System.out.print(myArray[i]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
Output:
2 3 1 
3 1 2 
1 2 3 
2 3 1 
3 1 2 
1 2 3
```

Comment: First of all you rather want to print after every swap.

Comment: Have you taken a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920315/permutation-of-array ? The second answer should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly though.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] myArray = {1, 2, 3};
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        print(myArray);
        int temp = myArray[i % myArray.length];
        myArray[i % myArray.length] = myArray[(i + 1) % myArray.length];
        myArray[(i + 1) % myArray.length] = temp;
    }
}

private static void print(int[] array) {
    for (int anArray : array) {
        System.out.print(anArray + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

**EDIT**:

I noticed, there is a wrong order, so it should be better:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] myArray = {1, 2, 3};

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        int idx = i % (myArray.length - 1);
        print(myArray);
        int temp = myArray[idx];
        myArray[idx] = myArray[idx + 1];
        myArray[idx + 1] = temp;
    }
}
```