# Arrays of int to one array

Tags: c#, arrays

Say I have following arrays of int:

```
var array1 = new[] {0, 2, 4, 6};
var array2 = new[] {0, 4, 5, 7};
var array3 = new[] {1, 4, 3, 5};
```

How do I merge this into one array of arrays so that the resulting is the list of all possible combinations of values in arrays? I.e. something similar to:

```
var resultingArray = new[] {new[] {0, 0, 1}, new[] {0, 4, 1}, new[] {0, 5, 1}....};
```

E.g. the length of arrays is the number of arrays I have but with the assumption that I do not know how many arrays I have and their length.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permutation of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920315/permutation-of-array)

Comment: This is not permutation. Check the definition for permutation.

Comment: It is not a permutation.  In SQL it would be a cross join.

Comment: I don't understand how [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920315/permutation-of-array) would help in my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as the N-ary Cartesian Product.

[Eric Lippert blogged a solution to this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx):

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combine<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] sequences)
{
    return Combine(sequences.AsEnumerable());
}

public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combine<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };

    return sequences.Aggregate(
        emptyProduct,
        (accumulator, sequence) =>
            from accseq in accumulator
            from item in sequence
            select accseq.Concat(new[] { item }));
}
```

This is how you could use it:

```
var array1 = new[] { 0, 2, 4, 6 };
var array2 = new[] { 0, 4, 5, 7 };
var array3 = new[] { 1, 4, 3, 5 };

var result = var result = Combine(array1, array2, array3);

var combinations = result.Select(x => x.ToArray()).ToArray();

foreach (var combination in combinations)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", combination));
```

Note that you don't actually need to convert the resulting enumerables into arrays like I did above, unless you need to pass them to methods that expect arrays.

You can use `result` directly like so:

```
foreach (var combination in result)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", combination));
```

Comment: But you need to enter all base-arrays by their name and you can´t do this manually. So this is very overloaded and complicated to read. But one way to do it.

Comment: Is there a generic solution? Say I don't know how many array I have and how long they are.

Comment: @Azimuth This *is* a generic solution. You can pass any number of arrays of any length (each array could be a different length).

Comment: What about int[][]? Or is that something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can´t merge them automatical and dynamic because your programm doesn´t know how manny and which arrays you got.
But you can easyly create an Array of Arrays, because you can hardcode it, like this:

```
int resultingArray[][] = new int[3][]; // 3 = X maybe
resultingArray [0] = array1;
resultingArray [1] = array2;
resultingArray [2] = array3;
// ... up to X
```

---

It will look like this if you visualize the structure:

```
[[0,2,4,6], [...], [...]]
```

Comment: Ok, then I guess that is not possible.

Comment: The data structre will be exactly like you want it if you visualize it.