# Print all combinations of java array containig different words

Tags: java, substring, permutation

I have an array with following elements = ["A","B","C"]

Now I want the output to be in the following manner-
A
B
BA
AB
AC
CA
BA
...
ABC
BCA
CAB

That is I want to find all the combinations of the elements of all lengths. Could anyone suggest me a java program to do the same thing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920315/permutation-of-array

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried.