# Number of different arrays from a given array

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array, say

```
{2, 3, 2, 3, 3}
```

I can swap **exactly 2 items**, e.g.

```
{2, 3, 2, 3, 3} => {3, 3, 2, 2, 3} 
 ^        ^
 swap these
```

How many *different arrays* can I produce this way? For the example above, the answer is **7**, these arrays are:

```
{2, 3, 2, 3, 3} // swap 2nd and 4th
{2, 2, 3, 3, 3} // swap 2nd and 3rd
{2, 3, 3, 2, 3} // swap 3rd and 4th
{2, 3, 3, 3, 2} // swap 3rd and 5th 
{3, 2, 2, 3, 3} // swap 1st and 2nd
{3, 3, 2, 2, 3} // swap 1st and 4th
{3, 3, 2, 3, 2} // swap 1st and 5th
```

If I have `{5, 5}` array (note, this is *degenerated* case), the answer is **1**: the only possibility is `{5, 5}` after swapping `5`s.

How to *start* this task? I am thinking about *nested* `for` loops, but I was told that I should do this in `O(NLog(N))` time.

This is my method signature:

```
public int process(List<Long> arr) {

}
```

Comment: @JanezKuhar, yes

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54274197/9474700

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: @RussJ, my attempt was completely wrong, so that's why I have not added here

Comment: @learner, that's fine, but it will at least give us a place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the problem in `O(n)` time. Let me explain the algorithm, and you'll implement it in Java.

Count each item occurence, organize them in a *map*. Here we have

```
  map = {
    {2, 2},  // number 2 appears 2 times
    {3, 3},  // number 3 appears 3 times
  }
```

If any number appears **2** or more times, start summation from `1` otherwise from `0`.

```
  Here we have number 2 appears 2 times, so we should start from 1

  sum = 1;
```

Then we loop over `array` and update both `map` and `sum`:

```
  v = array[i];
  sum += array.length - i - map[v];  
  map[v] -= 1;
```

Let's have a look what's going on:

```
  i : v :       sum :            map
  -----------------------------------
  0 : 2 : 1 + 3 = 4 : {{2, 1} {3, 3}}
  1 : 3 : 4 + 1 = 5 : {{2, 1} {3, 2}}
  2 : 2 : 5 + 2 = 7 : {{2, 0} {3, 2}}
  3 : 3 : 7 + 0 = 7 : {{2, 0} {3, 1}}
  4 : 3 : 7 + 0 = 7 : {{2, 0} {3, 0}}
```

Finally, return the `sum`.

**Edit:** Brief logics explanation:

If we have two or more *equal* items, then we can swap them and have the array *unchanged*. This is a *special solution* so we start summing from `1` in this case.

Now let's count all the swaps which *change* the array. Note, that when swapping we sould not count a swap *twice*:

```
 ... a ... b ...
     ^     ^
    swap(a, b) == swap(b, a)
```

To prevent this double count let operate with `swap(a, b)` only (`b` to the right of `a`). How many `swap (array[i], ...)` do we have?

```
 swap(array[i], array[i + 1])
 swap(array[i], array[i + 2])
 ...
 swap(array[i], array[length - 1])
```

we have `length - 1 - i` swaps. However, we should *subtract* the number of items to the right of `array[i]` which are *equal* to `array[i]` (swapping *equal* items doesn't produce a *new* array). With a help of `map` we can easily subtract the required number:

```
 map[array[i]] -= 1; // array[i] is not to the right of itself
 sum += length - 1 - i - map[array[i]]
```

Comment: This logic is solving my given sample inputs, can you please help me how this logic can solve the problem statement?

Comment: @learner: I've provided a brief explanation of the logic (see my edit)

Comment: @Janez Kuhar: Thank you! I've edited the answer

Comment: What if we have an array with a single element? `map[v] -= 1;` comes *before* `sum += array.length - i - map[v]; `, right?

Comment: @ Janez Kuhar: array with *single* element is *invalid*: "...I can swap **exactly 2** items..."

Comment: @Janez Kuhar: While coding I wanted to get rid of ` - 1` in `sum += array.length - i - map[v];` line: if you put `map` decrement *before* `sum += ` you have to subtract `1`. While explaining I found the `map`, `sum` order being a bit easier to digest.