# How to compute all the possible permutations given the characters of a given string?

Tags: java, string

I have written this code to find the possible permutation of string using iterative approach, but it's giving wrong output as follows. Please advise, what's wrong in the code?
Output I'm getting:

- BCAABC ACBABC ABCABC

Expetced output is :

- ABC ACB BAC BCA CBA CAB

  ```
   public class PrintPermutation {

       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

           String str = "ABC";
           String permutation = str + "";

           if (str.length() == 0) {
               System.out.println("String length is zero and can't make the permutation");
               return;
           }

           for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) 
           {

               char ch = str.charAt(i);
               String left = str.substring(0, i);
               String right = str.substring(i + 1);

               String Merge = left + right;

               System.out.println(Merge+ch+permutation);

           }
       }
   }
  ```

Comment: What is the output you get, what is the output you want?

Comment: Why you concat `str` with an empty string? Take care of javav naming conventions. variable names should start with lower case character

Comment: @Jens, output should be : ABC
ACB
BAC
BCA
CBA
CAB

Comment: Now is a good time to learn how to debug. It is very helpfull if you have such issues

Comment: it also looks like you are trying to imitate a recursive function but using iterative method.

Comment: @Tan Yu Hau Sean, it would be great, if you could help me to fix the code and post it as answer? Thank you. :)

Comment: It is not clear what your want as an output. You want all possible permutations? Please update your question and be more concrete.

Comment: Tan Yu Hau Sean, No, I'm trying out different approach and this tutorial link is different.

Comment: And what do these guys mean: BCAABC ACBABC ABCABC?

Comment: [This one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-permutations-of-a-string-in-java/) is the closest I can find that is similar to your code.

Comment: This is the output which I'm getting, which I have already mentioned in the question.

Comment: Because your question was unclear. A clear and concise way to ask your question would have been: `How to compute all the possible permutations given the characters of a given string?`

Comment: yezper, updated :), I did mention everything in the description though.

Comment: alright, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14444037/10671013) is a link that shows how to permutate an array if you are interested. I came across it as I was trying to emulate the method shown on this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/permutations-string-using-iteration/) in your case. So, what you could do if you arent interested in earlier links, is to treat your string as a char array and permutate the array.

Comment: Tan Yu Hau Sean, thank you, now it make sence. Acually I was asked this, question in interview, to print it iteratively, That's why I'm trying to achive it,recursive approach is easy. I did check : Johnson and Trotter algorithm as well.

Comment: then you could check this out. its one of the few iterative solutions i could find. everything else uses recursion somewhere https://www.techiedelight.com/find-permutations-string-cpp-java-iterative/

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution I found online. This one is interesting, because rather than using recursion or some complex iterative algorithm, they make the solution simpler by using some mathematical understanding. [link here](https://www.pepcoding.com/resources/online-java-foundation/string,-string-builder-and-arraylist/print_all_permutations_of_a_string_iteratively/topic)

```
public static void permutateString2(String s){
        int len = s.length();
        int factorial = factorial(s.length());

        for (int i=0; i<factorial; i++){
            String str = s;
            int counter = 0;
            StringBuilder permutation = new StringBuilder();

            while (counter < len){
                
                int idx = i % (len - counter);
                
                permutation.append(str.charAt(idx));
                
                if (idx == 0){
                    str = str.substring(idx+1);
                }else if (idx == str.length()-1){
                    str = str.substring(0, str.length()-1);
                }else{
                    str = str.substring(0, idx) + str.substring(idx+1, str.length());
                }
                
                counter++;
            }
            System.out.println(permutation.toString());
        }
    }

    private static int factorial(int n){
        int result = 1;
        for (int i=1; i<= n; i++){
            result *= i;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I just noticed that the link also provides some source code, but because I just stumbled through their logic/pseudocode, so mine may seem janky